# Set string color using java

Tags: java, string, fonts, colors

- I have the below servlet code.
- While printing the below line in console, it should be printed in red color. "*Connection name "+cname+" already exists. Please try with another name". how to get this.

My servlet code:

```
  try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+host+":"+port+"/"+service,username,password);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            if(con!=null){
                if(key == null){ 
                    out.println("Connected Successfully");
                    String rootPath=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                    System.out.println(rootPath);
                    String propPath=rootPath+"/WEB-INF/";
                    PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(propPath+"importedDB.properties", true)));
                    out1.println(cname+"=jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+host+","+port+","+service+","+username+","+password);
                    out1.close();
                }
                else{                   
                    out.println("*Connection name "+cname+" already exists. Please try with another name");
                }
             }else{
                 out.println("Error in getting connection");
             }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You are writing code to `access database` and `write some text in console` in your `servlet` !!!

Comment: @Apurv the problem is not who taught her Java, is who taught her web programming, because there are **lot of misconceptions** in the question (and in the code).

Answer (score 0):

You can try jlibs (http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/AnsiColoring) which has Ansi Colors in Console Output.